# How do I groupby activity with hours data type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

I have been trying to sum the hours by activity in a dataframe but it didn't work.

the code:

```
import pandas as pd

fileurl   = r'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WuvvsZCfbcioYLvwwHuSunUbs4tjvv05/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105286407332351152540&rtpof=true&sd=true'
df = pd.read_excel(fileurl, header=0)
df.groupby('Activity').sum()
```

excel link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WuvvsZCfbcioYLvwwHuSunUbs4tjvv05/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105286407332351152540&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: You have to clean your excel file first. Remove trailing spaces then fix (for walking) `=B2+15`

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed the excel file, but the python code is still not working

Comment: I am not able to read your excel file. Link the raw data itself, not the file.

Comment: I have shared a new link

Answer (score 0):

You have to force `hours` column to be strings else you will get `datetime.time` instance.

```
df = pd.read_excel(fileurl, header=0, dtype={'hours': str})

out = (df.assign(hours=pd.to_timedelta(df['hours']))
         .groupby('Activity', as_index=False)['hours'].sum())
print(out)

# Output
      Activity           hours
0  bushwalking 0 days 04:45:00
1      cycling 0 days 11:30:00
2     football 0 days 03:42:00
3          gym 0 days 07:00:00
4     running  0 days 14:00:00
5     swimming 0 days 13:15:00
6     walking  0 days 04:00:00
```

Comment: error ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed

Comment: Did you run the code with your sample file?

Comment: Yes, I ran the code with the sample

Comment: Can you append `abs()` after `pd.to_timedelta(df['hours']).abs()` please

Comment: Now it works, but in another data frame, the sum of hours is not correct.